# How to render multiple result from MySQL query on the same .ejs file on Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm now learning Node.js and creating a web application, but don't know how to render twice on the same `.ejs` file.

So in the following `.ejs` file:

```
<table>
<% rows.forEach(function(ind){ %>
/* map each value of each field to table */
<% }) %>
</table>

<table>
<% rows2.forEach(function(ind){ %>
/* map each value of each field to table */
<% }) %>
</table>
```

And I want to execute two separate queries and render them to the same `.ejs` file, but when I tried to, I can't since at the time when I tried to run first query and render it to the above `.ejs` file I don't have the result from second query which spits out values for the second table (i.e. `row2` data). How can I deal with it? Or do I have to make two separate `.ejs` file and do rendering twice in a nested form? I like to avoid a nested file as best as possible, so if there were any solutions please tell me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wait until both queries are done before you render the result :)

Conceptually:

```
db.query(QUERY1, function(err, result1) {
  db.query(QUERY2, function(err, result2) {
    res.render('template', { rows : result1, rows2: result2 });
  });
});
```

Instead of nesting functions like that, you could take a look at [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel), which would make the above code look like this:

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) { db.query(QUERY1, callback) },
  function(callback) { db.query(QUERY2, callback) }
], function(err, results) {
  res.render('template', { rows : results[0], rows2 : results[1] });
});
```

The advantage of using `async.parallel` is that both queries will run parallel to each other, instead of sequentially as in the first example. So the response will (might) be quicker.

Comment: I'm now reading a document on `async.parallel` but it sounds a great fit. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't go deeply into reading the document, but when I tried, the argument variable `results` returned list of list, which consisted of rows and fields. So I changed `rows: result[0]` to `rows: result[0][0]` and got what I expected.

Comment: @user2360798 ah right, I forgot that `node-mysql` calls the callback with two arguments instead of just one :)